# How to programmatically remove a UViewController from the stack

Tags: ios, swift

i have an application with two view controllers. I am able to present the second view controller programmatically (which I use a custom popup/ alert) but I am not able to programatically remove it.  I do not want to use UINavigationController.

```
 // SHOW ALERT - UIViewcontroller - 1
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let popUp = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupEmpty")
 self.present(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)


 // HIDE ALERT - UIViewController -2 

let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let popUpVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupEmpty")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(popUpVC, animated: true) // ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **present** something, you need to **dismiss**.

```
self.dimiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you **push** something, you need to **pop**.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss ViewController as you are presenting ViewController to show Alert. Write below code when you are done with presented ViewController:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```